# BULK INSERT from CSV does not read last row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, csv, bulkinsert

I have the following T-SQL statement:

```
BULK INSERT #TempTable
FROM "C:\csvfile.csv"
WITH ( FIELDTERMINATOR = ',', ROWTERMINATOR ='\n', FIRSTROW = 2, KEEPIDENTITY )
```

I am test running it on a 3 row csv file, of which the first row contains the headers. So there are 2 data rows.

However, it only reads line 2 and never line 3.

Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe a missing line break after the last row of the CSV?

Comment: That's what I was wondering too.

Answer (score 2):

A line break was needed after the last row. Ugh.

Comment: Yep, I found the same thing.  I was concerned that an extra line-break would cause it to think that there was an extra row of data.  This wasn't the case.  Putting the extra line-break made it work for me.