# BULK INSERT missing last row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, coldfusion, bulkinsert

I use BULK INSERT for my text files. Everything works fine but one thing that I discovered, If I give the final line's final column a value, it will import. If the value of that final column in the final line is blank, it discards the line, despite the fact that the destination column allows nulls! Text file uses tab delimiter, here is example of the last row data:

```
Mike    Johnson 1/29/1987   M
```

if I have any value in the last column field row will be inserted, example here:

```
Mike    Johnson 1/29/1987   M   test
```

This is my BULK Insert:

```
BULK INSERT ##TEMP_TEXT
FROM '#uncdir#\#cffile.ServerFile#'
WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR = '\t', 
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)
```

I tried to use `\r` instead of `\n` but that did not fix the problem. I also researched on some websites but could not find any solution. I'm wondering this is something that can be fixed in SQL. If someone knows how this can be fixed please let me know.

SOLUTION:

For anyone how use ColdFusion here is the line that will add newline in the text file.

```
exec xp_cmdshell 'echo. >> "#uncdir#\#cffile.ServerFile#"';
```

Key was to put double quotes around coldfusion variables, otherwise code does not work.

uncdir code is here:

```
<cfset uncdir = createObject("java","java.net.InetAddress").getLocalHost().getHostName()/>
```

`cffile.ServerFile` you can get from the form. I used JQuery to submit the text file. I hope this helps. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try with `\r\n`?

Comment: I tried but that causes the error: coldfusion.tagext.sql.QueryTag$DatabaseQueryException: Error Executing Database Query.

Comment: Also I tried to use '0x0a' for the rowdeterminator.

Comment: The last field doesn't have a tab to finish the line? Because even for `NULL` values that last delimiter needs to be there AFAICT.

Comment: I have a tab and empty value/field. In that case my insert skips the last row. If I put any value like I showed above then row will be inserted in db.

Comment: Just to rule out possible bugs, did you install the [latest SP](https://sqlserverbuilds.blogspot.be/)?

Comment: Perhaps you just need to append a terminating newline? I read that in a [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10317210/243373).

Comment: @TT. Link: latest SP does not work. I do not know what you mean by append a terminating newline?

Comment: Just before you process the file, append a newline to the file.

Comment: Is that the only solution for this problem? Also if I have to append a newline can I do that with SQL or I have to do that before the BULK INSERT?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128650/discussion-between-tt-and-espresso-coffee).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I reproduced your issue on SQL Server 2008 R2. The solution is as simple as adding a newline to your file so that the last row terminates with a newline.

I created two files:

1. [image: without_newline]
2. [image: with_newline]

Then ran the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE #t(first_name VARCHAR(128),last_name_etc VARCHAR(128),sex CHAR(1),test VARCHAR(128));

BULK INSERT #t
FROM 'C:\temp\without_newline.txt'
WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR='\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR='\n'
);

SELECT * FROM #t;

TRUNCATE TABLE #t;

BULK INSERT #t
FROM 'C:\temp\with_newline.txt'
WITH (
    FIELDTERMINATOR='\t',
    ROWTERMINATOR='\n'
);

SELECT * FROM #t;

DROP TABLE #t;
```

Result 1:

```
first_name  | last_name_etc     | sex | test
--------------------------------------------
Tom         | Jackson 2/28/1986 | M   | test
```

Result 2:

```
first_name  | last_name_etc     | sex | test
--------------------------------------------
Tom         | Jackson 2/28/1986 | M   | test
Mike        | Johnson 1/29/1987 | M   | NULL
```

---

The solution should be as simple as making sure the last line terminates with `\r\n`. Either you change the process that generates the text file or do it manually right before you do the bulk insert.

One way to do this manually would be to run `EXEC xp_cmdshell 'echo. >> C:\temp\without_newline.txt'` right before you do the bulk insert.

Comment: I finally got this to work, adding new line and that solved the problem. Here is one thing that came across my mind while I was working on this code. Command cmdshell is adding new line to the file, how I will be able to detect the root/folder of the file if it's not on my computer? Let's say some other user wants to upload his/her file and that file is on their computer. In that case directory that I'm using will be different and that will case the problem.

Comment: Hi @espresso_coffee. I'm not entirely sure I'm following. There is no "detection" involved for the `data_file` in a bulk insert command. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx#Anchor_1) says: *"data_file must specify **a valid path from the server on which SQL Server is running.** If data_file is a remote file, **specify the Universal Naming Convention (UNC) name**."*. It is possible though that the SQL Server account doesn't have write-access. In that case there isn't much you can do. Maybe copy the file to which the account does have write-access?

Comment: @espresso_coffee It's probably better though to have the process that generates the data file generate it with a terminating newline.

Comment: I got this to work finally. Problem was in double quotes around my coldfusion variable that I was outputting in xp_cmdshell command. Now I'm adding newline to each file that has been uploaded. Thanks for all your help. And I think this is the only solution for this problem. I could not find anything else on the web that can fix this bug.

Comment: If somebody uploads their file, a copy goes to your server using code that should be available to you or a co-worker.  That code can put the file wherever you want.

Comment: .. and since the file is uploaded to the CF server, it can also be manipulated with CF code as well.