# BULK INSERT fails with last row

Tags: sql-server, csv, bulkinsert

I'm importing a CSV using sql server bulk option and below is my sql inputs.

```
MAXERRORS = 1000000,
CODEPAGE = 1251,
FIELDTERMINATOR = '~%',
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a',
ERRORFILE = 'C:\MyFile_BadData.log'
```

My problem is BULK INSERT fails to load the last row data.

Also please note that no errors was reported by the sql bulk option..

If i add a empty newline to the file the loading works without any issues.

But my concern is i cannot modify the CSV file, please suggest your valuable inputs if any

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40727993/bulk-insert-missing-last-row

Comment: Whoever generated it has given you an invalid file

Answer (score 4):

This happens when the last line doesn't end with the row terminator. Make sure the last line ends with the row terminator, then the last row will be imported.

If you can't change the export routine that generates the CSV, use powershell or something to add the row terminator to the CSV. If you can't change the original, copy it to a location where you can change it (include that in your powershell script).

Answer (score 0):

Exactly!  The last character in the file must be some kind of special character; Line Break, Space, etc.  Can you simply delete the last line and do the import?  If you need an automated solution, create a small C# app to open the file, delete the last line, and then save the file.  THEN, run your import process.  This can all be controlled using the Windows Task Scheduler, so you can even run it as an overnight job, when you are far away from your computer.

https://www.digitalcitizen.life/how-create-task-basic-task-wizard

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a Unix variant, you can also use this to add to the file without having to edit it by hand.

```
sed -i '' -e '$a\' fname.csv
```

Note that this will only add a newline if there isn't one. So running it multiple times will not affect a file that already has a trailing newline.